# Cannot connect to Google Compute Engine instance via SSH

Tags: ssh, sshd, dovecot, mail-server, google-compute-engine

i am new to google cloud,i just deployed my first instance it was working fine till yesterday, i used last time to set email server using this tutorial [email server](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-2-arming-your-server-with-postfix-dovecot/4/), but now i am unable to connect ssh in browser and also with google cloud sdk in terminal.

Website is running fine,I don't know what happened Please help

the error message in browser

```
Connection Failed, and we are unable to connect VM on port 22.
```

the error message in terminal

```
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

And serial console output its shows

```
Jul 8 10:09:26 Instance sshd[10103]: error: Could not load host key:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

Jul 8 10:09:27 Instance sshd[10103]: User username from 0.0.0.0 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers

Jul 8 10:09:27 Instance sshd[10103]: input_userauth_request: invalid user username [preauth] Jul 8 10:09:27 Instance sshd[10103]: Connection closed by 0.0.0.0 [preauth] –
```

Answer (score 0):

You were changing sshd configuration and you put some `AllowUsers` or `DenyUsers` options in `sshd_config` or something like this, which is preventing you from logging in. Not sure what exactly is it from this report.

You can try to log in with different user, but if you are not sure about configuration, it will probably not help.

I'm not familiar with google-compute-engine, but if you can connect using serial console and post you `sshd_config`, we can diagnose and probably fix the problem.